# Tower location in Android

Tags: android

Below is my code:

```
private Location getLastKnownLoaction(boolean enabledProvidersOnly){

    LocationManager manager = mActivityContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location location = null;
    List<String> providers = manager.getProviders(enabledProvidersOnly)

    for(String provider : providers){
        location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        //maybe try adding some Criteria here
        if(location != null) return location;
    }

    //at this point we've done all we can and no location is returned
    return null;
}
```

I have seen tower location being displayed in older Nokia phones. How do I implement similar functionality in Android?"

Comment: You want to show tower location in your android phone ?

Comment: yes i want to show tower location in my android phone

Comment: @.user3363604 did u got the correct answer?

Comment: No, can you please help me

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have this on your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

And also must try it on real device not simulator.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get only tower location in android. What you can do is following :

In your manifest, add permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

and in your code, use

```
Location location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

It helps you retrieve network based location. If its course, It will provide you with Tower based location most probably.

Also if you get a null in getting last location, you can request for a new location.

Comment: location may not be accurate, but mate it is possible to do so. Everything is possible in this world :) :D

Comment: Tower locations are never accurate, they are not meant to be accurate they are just an estimation of the location that you can be in. And the above code does that :)

I think thats what the question asked for.

Comment: Don't get angry ur rit :P :) :D :D

Comment: No no I was just trying to address the question using minimal code. That should always be our priority :)

Comment: rit, ohk ur nice person ;)

Comment: Its good for getting the most accurate location at any given point that a provider can provide with but not the Tower based location. And also so many permissions are not required. For location, you just need "Location_fine" and "location_course" permissions

Comment: Its not wrong, just different approaches. For tower based location, you dont need a provider that gives you fine location.